# Pokemon X Can't Find Mega Stones

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm trying to look for the garchompite stone, but when I'm at the spot I don't see it anywhere. I have battled Serena, talked to professor Sycamore after, and appeared there between 8PM-9PM. Though, when I'm there I see that the sky isn't dark and it seems that it is day in the game. I've tried tweaking the time setting and date setting on the 3DS and still won't get it to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you beaten the Elite Four? This is a post-game stone.

Comment: Yes I have beaten the elite four.